# How to make phases in thread cycle?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I've got thread class which increments `lable` value from 0 to n. Thread code:

```
public class 

    SimpleThread implements Runnable {

            Thread t;
            volatile boolean stop = true;
        int n;
        JLabel label;
        String name;

        SimpleThread(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            t = new Thread(this, "settingThread");
            t.start();
        }


        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                while (stop) {


                }

                System.out.println(name + " stop:" + stop);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }
                }
                stop = true;

            }
        }

        public void start(int n, JLabel label) {
            stop = false;
            this.n = n;
            this.label = label;
        }
    }
```

Thread must work until `stop` value isn't `true`. Also I've got 2 thread objects `st1` and `st2` with different arguments:

```
st1.start(10, timeLabel1);
st2.start(5, timeLabel2);
```

So first thread should increment `timeLabel1` from 0 to 10 and `st2` - from 0 to 5. And now the question. How can I make my programm wait until threads has passed the stage in the cycle? I mean something like this:

```
 public void run() {
            while (true) {

                while (stop) {


                }

                System.out.println(name + " stop:" + stop);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }
                }
                stop = true;
                //stage

            }
        }
```

And then:

```
st1.start(10, timeLabel1);
        st2.start(5, timeLabel2);
        //wait until both stages aren't done
        System.out.println("yep");
```

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Администратор
 * Date: 22.11.13
 * Time: 21:17
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class StackOverflow implements ActionListener {
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");

    SimpleThread st1 = new SimpleThread("1st"), st2 = new SimpleThread("2nd");

    JLabel timeLabel1 = new JLabel("0"), timeLabel2 = new JLabel("0");


    StackOverflow() {


        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Strategy fighting");
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(300, 150);

        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        button.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.add(button);
        jfrm.add(timeLabel1);
        jfrm.add(timeLabel2);


        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }


    public class SimpleThread implements Runnable {

        Thread t;
        volatile boolean stop = true;
        int n;
        JLabel label;
        String name;

        SimpleThread(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            t = new Thread(this, "settingThread");
            t.start();
        }


        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                while (stop) {


                }

                System.out.println(name + " stop:" + stop);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }
                }
                stop = true;


            }
        }

        public void start(int n, JLabel label) {
            stop = false;
            this.n = n;
            this.label = label;
        }
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        st1.start(10, timeLabel1);
        st2.start(5, timeLabel2);

        System.out.println("yep");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new StackOverflow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait and notify should be able to do this. http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/

Comment: too many code and too little description of what you want. Лениво разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

Your question already has the answer: the [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) class. ;)

Something like this should do the trick:

```
static final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(NUM_THREADS + 1); // +1 for the main thread
```

In your threads:

```
run() {
  // do stage 1
  phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // wait until everyone is done with stage 1
  // do stage 2
}
```

And in your main:

```
startThreads(NUM_THREADS);
phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // wait until stage 1 is done
// ... do something else
```

Comment: But my threads work in cycle. So after 1st iteration my thread will be in 1st phase for all time.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem. If you do not want to use the Phaser again, you don't need to. You can as well unregister clients from the Phaser, i.E. you can unregister the main thread if you want to only synchronize them on the first cycle.